# scpは不可能でrcpなら可能な理由は？

Tags: linux, scp

仕事上、サーバ間でファイル転送を行おうとしています。

環境に詳しい方に転送方法のアドバイスを頂いたところ、
scpはできず、rcpなら可能な環境だと言われました。

なぜscpは不可能でrcpなら可能といったことが
起こるのでしょうか？

Comment: 運用ルールなのか単に設定していないだけなのかは分かりませんが、この場合まずは実際の環境に詳しい人に確認すべきなのかなと思います。

Answer (score 2):

[`scp`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)は[`ssh`（セキュアシェル）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)の一部で22/tcpを使用します。
[`rcp`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rcp)は[`rsh`（リモートシェル）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AB)の一部で514/tcpを使用します。

当然ですが、クライアント・サーバー両側で適切に設定されていなければどちらも使用できません。`ssh`のための設定がされておらず、リモートシェルは設定されているだけのことでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

(1)sshdがインストールされていない、またはインストールされていてもsshdが起動されていない
(2)ssh通信で使用するwell-knownポート(22番ポート)が遮断されている
という状態であれば、scpを含むssh系の通信は不可能であると思います。

sshが普及し始めたのは2000年以降ぐらいでいまどきのLinux/UNIX環境はあまり無いことだとは思いますが、
それ以前に構築されていて、時代から取り残されているような環境ってあるのかもしれません。

(それが良いか悪いかは本筋ではないので述べませんけど…。)

Comment: 21/tcpはftpですね。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。